# Iterating over an unorganized dataset to combine two columns with a condition using pandas library

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({0: ['MIT', 'UCSD', 'Stanford','NaN','NaN'],
                   1: ['CS  College', 'E College', 'X College','UCSD','NaN'],
                   2: ['CS Department', 'Art Department', 'X Department','Sixth College','UCSD'],
                   3: ['NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN','Math Department','Med College'],
                   4: ['NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN','NaN','Anatomy Department']})

Out[12]: df1

          0            1               2                3                   4
0       MIT  CS  College   CS Department              NaN                 NaN
1      UCSD    E College  Art Department              NaN                 NaN
2  Stanford    X College    X Department              NaN                 NaN
3       NaN         UCSD   Sixth College  Math Department                 NaN
4       NaN          NaN            UCSD      Med College  Anatomy Department
```

I would like to combine each college with its department only if the school is UCSD and add a new column and name it College/Department. The problem is that the dataset is not organized where if you noticed, UCSD is not always located under one column but located in columns 0,1 and 2.
         I was able to combine college and department of UCSD only one time (not for every other UCSD) and only when I know the column index like this:

```
        df2 = df1[df1[0]=='UCSD']
        df2['College/Department']= df2[1]+" - "+df2[2]
        df2

        or 


        df2 = df1[df1[1]=='UCSD']
        df2['College/Department']= df2[2]+" - "+df2[3]
        df2
```

My question is that if I have a large dataset and I don't know where
        is UCSD exactly located how can I iterate all rows and columns and check if there is UCSD then combine the next two columns automatically for the same row that has UCSD?

```
    Basically to have a dataset looks like this:

            df3 = pd.DataFrame({ 
                           0: ['UCSD','NaN','NaN'],
                           1: ['Art and Science College', 'UCSD','NaN'],
                           2: [ 'Art Department','Sixth College','UCSD'],
                           3: ['NaN','Math Department','Med College'],
                           4: ['NaN','NaN','Anatomy Department'],
                           'College/Department':['Art and Science College - Art Department','Sixth College - CS Deprtment','Med College - Anatomy Department']})


Out[12]: df3


        0       1               2                      3                   4          College/Department             
1      UCSD    E College  Art Department              NaN                 NaN         E College-Art Department  
3       NaN         UCSD   Sixth College  Math Department                 NaN         Sixth College-Math Department
4       NaN          NaN            UCSD      Med College  Anatomy Department         Med College-Anatomy Department
```

Comment: Where does the data come from? Might it be possible to fix things earlier in the program?

Comment: I just created it to reflect another dataset that I scraped from a website that has problems similar to this post

Comment: Does it still accurately reflect the original situation? How straightforward is the web scraping?

Comment: Yep, it reflects the original situation. For web scraping, it depends on the web page itself. Some web pages are not easy to scrape because of the structure of the web page itself(HTML). But I found a tool and it helps some times here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-scraper/jnhgnonknehpejjnehehllkliplmbmhn?hl=en                                                   but  I belief mastering scraping using programming languages such as python will save your time from editing the data you got from scraping.

Comment: _but I belief mastering scraping using programming languages such as python will save your time from editing the data you got from scraping._ Hopefully, yes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Python 3.8 solution with walrus operator:

```
df1['College/Department'] = df1.apply(lambda x: x[idx+1]+'-'+x[idx+2] if any(x[(idx:=i)] == 'UCSD' for i in range(len(x))) else np.nan, axis=1)
df1 = df1.dropna(subset=['College/Department'])
print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
      0          1               2                3                   4              College/Department
1  UCSD  E College  Art Department              NaN                 NaN        E College-Art Department
3   NaN       UCSD   Sixth College  Math Department                 NaN   Sixth College-Math Department
4   NaN        NaN            UCSD      Med College  Anatomy Department  Med College-Anatomy Department
```

---

The same but for Python <3.8:

```
def fn(l):
    try:
        idx = l.tolist().index('UCSD')
        return l[idx+1]+'-'+l[idx+2]
    except ValueError:
        return np.nan

df1['College/Department'] = df1.apply(fn, axis=1)
df1 = df1.dropna(subset=['College/Department'])
print(df1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your time but I keep getting this error:                                  df1['College/Department'] = df1.apply(lambda x: x[idx+1]+'-'+x[idx+2] if any(x[(idx:=i)] == 'UCSD' for i in range(len(x))) else np.nan, axis=1)
                                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Abraham You're probably not using Python version 3.8. Try the other version I posted in my answer.